# Rename a branch when pulling it from Github

Tags: git, github

I have a local branch called "my-change". I pushed it to GitHub.

Now I want to pull the branch from Github onto my local machine. I want to keep my original "my-change" branch in its current state. So I want to pull GitHub's "my-change" as a separate branch from local "my-change".

How can I pull the branch from GitHub, and name it as "my-change-from-github" on local?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have GitHub set up as a remote named `origin`:

```
git fetch
git checkout -b my-change-from-github origin/my-change
```

After running these operations, you will have what was the latest `my-change` upstream checked out as a local branch called `my-change-from-github`.

Do not do a `git pull` or `git rebase` on your local `my-change` branch or it will be updated.

Answer (score 0):

Clear your `my-change` branch's tracking:

```
git branch --unset-upstream my-change
```

Make a new branch tracking `origin`'s `my-change`:

```
git branch my-change-from-github origin/my-change
```

(when you branch off a remote-tracking branch, git automatically sets up tracking for it by default)